# why is the video sequencer so slow with 4k files 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

currently trying to figure out blender's video editing using Mikeycal Meyers video series and it is all seeming to work but no matter what preferences I change the sequencer responds and plays back incredibly slow with a 4k mov file. I've set the memory cache past the amount of ram I have (16) and have tried different clips. Could use some advice.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use all your RAM in one cache setting. You need to consider memory space required by other fundamental process. Most of the operating system are able to use more RAM rather the actual physic size by **disk cache(and compress)** (this is not the one mention in blender). But using these cache will cause the slow down due to memory is from slow disk rather then high speed RAM with swapping. You should leave 2~5 GB size for the other setting to prevent overuse of RAM

Comment: And also, 4K is actually a quite high resolution in processing. Unless Blender start to use modern structure to deal with these video, it is hard to let Blender manipulate these file fluently.

Comment: If you expect to edit in 4k, blender might not be the right tool. Blender's video editing capabilities are quite limited and not very efficient. Try using a dedicated video editing app.